# Why setting setState in componentWillUnmount solves this React error?

Tags: reactjs

The error is:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
> componentWillUnmount method.

I tried using a variable (isMounted for example) to conditionally call setState. And it didn't work but placing this line in componentWillUnmount worked:

```
this.setState = ()=>{};
```

What is happening here?

Comment: What is the code for the rest of `componentWillUnmount()`?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you are overwriting `setState` function so the component is not updated and error is not reproducible anymore.

Comment: @kinduser Understood however, can this solution cause any hidden or not obvious problems?

Comment: @user33276346 if `_isMounted` approach doesnt work for you, the problem probably lays somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you everything: `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component`. If your component unmounts it gets disposed and you can no longer set its state. `this.setState = ()=>{};` alleviates this problem by overwriting React's implementation of `setState` and causing it to do nothing.

Comment: Does doing this have any negative consequence?

Comment: The component will get disposed after this so I think it's safe. However, why are you setting the state on unmount? It doesn't make sense